# Image pixel relocation

Tags: image

I have a *n* x *m* x 3 matrix where the current locations relate to the source the image came from. I'm trying to map the image to another source. The image is of size *n* x *m* and I have the spacial `x` and `y` positions of the pixel in the first and second layer respectively, and the intensity value of the pixel in the 3rd layer. I need to somehow reorganize the pixels and display them according to the spatial locations stored in the first two layers.

This means that in `img(i,j,:)` I have the `x` position, the `y` position, and the gray scale pixel value.

Is there any way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i got you right.
1- Get min and max x on the first layer
2- Get min and max y on second layer
3- Get min and max intensity on third layer
4- Create an image large enough too handle all x,y,intensity.
   (this might involve translating / scaling if you have constraints on your image size)
5- then draw all (x,y,i) in your image.